# In Android Studio Why scrollView is not showing all the text view i inserted in

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, scrollview

1. Scroll View
2. Text View
3. Android Development
4. Linear Layout

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, 1. please include 2. enough information 3.for others 4.to recreate the problem 5. exactly, as we can't just guess or assume what you have now. include your code as text, here

Answer (score -2):

Use NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView